# Logger in Django is somehow logging all SQL queries even though its not supposed to

Tags: django, logging, django-settings

So I work in a new place and I do not know everything about the project and there is no one who has answer to my question, no documentation, etc.
The problem is: loggers are completely unreadable, many errors, almost everything important is logged to one file and the worst is that all SQL queries/requests to DB are logged, and I do not need them at all.

Here is my logging config, I do not see anything related to SQL logging here, how can i find where in my project SQL logging is enabled?

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '#######\n{asctime}\n {message}\n#######',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/sites/moneycase/logs/django_error.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'ubki': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/sites/moneycase/logs/ubki.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'ipay': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/sites/moneycase/logs/ipay.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'root_file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/sites/moneycase/logs/root.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'ubki': {
            'handlers': ['ubki'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'ipay': {
            'handlers': ['ipay'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['root_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

Comment: guys any1 can help me on this one?